# Making relative clauses in passive and active forms for every part of a sentence

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, relative-clauses

I have a base sentence as follows.

> AさんはBさんに足を踏まれました。(A's feet was stepped on by B.)

I am trying to make a relative clause for Aさん, Bさん, and 足 each as follows.

## Aさん

- Passive: Bさんに足を踏まれた**人**はAさんです。
- Active: Bさんが足を踏んだ**人**はAさんです。

## Bさん

- Passive: Aさんが足を踏まれた**人**はBさんです。
- Active: Aさんの足を踏んだ**人**はBさんです。

## 足

- Passive: AさんがBさんに踏まれた**器官**は足です。
- Active: BさんがAさんに踏んだ**器官**は足です。

Are there any grammatical mistakes in my sentences above?

Comment: +1 素晴らしい質問だと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the sentences but the last one are correct. It should be BがA**を**踏んだところは足だ. (器官 sounds too anatomical.)